# Can you run multiple sites from one Magento Bridge, with different styling?

Tags: magento-enterprise

You can set-up multiple sites to run from 1 Magento Bridge installation, I can't however work out how to display different styling for each of the sites/profiles.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You need to create different theme for every website/stores and assign theme from admin to website/stores

Comment: It's specifically regarding the Payment Bridge styling. Any experience of this?

Comment: It doesn't matter which styling you want to change. Set a theme and then create the templates in your theme, which you want to change.

Comment: @RyanAtkins, you have to specify more precisely what this `Bridge`/`Payment Bridge` is ans what do you want to style. Looks like everyone here are misled (or just me).

Comment: I'm not sure of the how, but what is being talked of here is the Magento EE Payment Bridge. It serves the payment forms up on Magento via an iframe, and the templates in the Magento install are not used to display the forms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at version 1.6 of BridgeConnect and there does not appear to be a way to configure theme/css settings or specify them at runtime. The only answer I can offer is to contact EE support.